# Error while installing RPMFORGE in CENTOS 7

Tags: centos

When i try to install rpmforge (i need to install phpmyadmin) i get this error, any help would be greatly appreciated!

[root@plasticarmy ~]# yum http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

No such command: http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help
[root@plasticarmy ~]#

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close, but you're missing "install" in the above yum command.

First, if you haven't already, import the key ->

```
sudo rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
```

Then 'yum install' ->

```
sudo yum install http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

as root and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it was due to the fact that i was installing the wrong package, Note that "rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1" is a 0.5.3-1 release.

When I got the right release "epel-release-7-0.2" which is 7-0.2 as per the command:
sudo rpm -Uvh http://fedora.mirrors.romtelecom.ro/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/epel-release-7-0.2.noarch.rpm

The installation of the package was successful, and I could install phpMyAdmin later.

P.S: my CentOS is 7.